# How to not allow values that are not in the database in an Autocomplete form with PHP & JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete function with a form where the name of the city is type into.  All possible values are in a database and are pull out of the database and store them in the variable $list

Then I have my form with the input and the button

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="searchresults.php" >
    <input id="hero-demo" autofocus type="search" name="search" placeholder="City" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

and the autocomplete function:

```
   <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#hero-demo').autoComplete({
            minChars: 1,
            source: function(term, suggest){
                term = term.toLowerCase();
                var choices = [<?= $list ?>];
                var suggestions = [];
                for (i=0;i<choices.length;i++)
                    if (~choices[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) suggestions.push(choices[i]);
                suggest(suggestions);
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

How can I do, so if for instance the user introduce the value "London" and that value is not in my database ($list) then the Search button doesn't work.

Thank you very much

Comment: What you want, submit the form or blur the `#hero-demo` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could add on `submit` event in your js code then do what you want before submiting the form and you should remove inline-event from your HTML code in this case.

**HTML :**

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="searchresults.php" >
```

**JS :**

```
$('form[name="form1"]').on('submit', function(e){
     //Prevent form submiting after click on submit button
     e.preventDefault(); 

     //Do what you want
     $('#hero-demo').blur();

     //Submit the form
     $(this).submit();
});
```

Hope this helps.